# BootstrapDialog doesn´t close the dialog

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am playing with  bootstrap-table and bootstrap-dialog.

When I click in a row I need to show a dialog with bootstrapDialog. This is working well.

If I click on "Yes" I need execute some code and close the window. If CI lick "No", I only close the window.

My problem is when I click Yes, an alert function is called but the dialog is never closed. I need to close the dialog automatically after return from called function.

What am I missing here?

Here is link to test: http://jsfiddle.net/aoh4yamr/10/

```
var data = [
    {
        "name": "bootstrap-table",
        "stargazers_count": "526",
        "forks_count": "122",
        "description": "An extended Bootstrap table with radio, checkbox, sort, pagination, and other added features. (supports twitter bootstrap v2 and v3) "
    },
    {
        "name": "multiple-select",
        "stargazers_count": "288",
        "forks_count": "150",
        "description": "A jQuery plugin to select multiple elements with checkboxes :)"
    },
    {
        "name": "bootstrap-show-password",
        "stargazers_count": "32",
        "forks_count": "11",
        "description": "Show/hide password plugin for twitter bootstrap."
    },
    {
        "name": "blog",
        "stargazers_count": "13",
        "forks_count": "4",
        "description": "my blog"
    },
    {
        "name": "scutech-redmine",
        "stargazers_count": "6",
        "forks_count": "3",
        "description": "Redmine notification tools for chrome extension."
    }
];

$(function () {
    $('#table').bootstrapTable({
        data: data
    });
});

function commonFormatter(value) {
    return '<div data-field="' + this.field + '">' + value + '</div>';
}


window.commonEvents = {

  'click div': function (e) {
function doFunctionEditForYes() {
  alert("ok");
              };

BootstrapDialog.show({
                        title: 'Hello',
                        message: 'Edit?',
                        buttons: [ {
                            label: 'Yes',
                            cssClass: 'btn-success',
                            action: function(dialogRef) {
                                doFunctionEditForYes();
                                dialogRef.close;
                            }
                        }, {
                            label: 'No',
                            cssClass: 'btn-warning',
                            action: function(dialogItself){
                                dialogItself.close();
                        }
                        }]
                    });
    }
}
```

Comment: As it says in the question, he needs code to run then close the dialog.

Comment: @Ivan Barayev When I click in  a row table, the bootstrap dialog appears. Then I click Yes, after that, a alert ("OK") is showing. After come back to Boootstrap dialog I only can close it, if I click in the (x) of the dialog. The dialog should close automatically after return from alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are just using dialogRef.close

```
                        buttons: [ {
                        label: 'Yes',
                        cssClass: 'btn-success',
                        action: function(dialogRef) {
                            doFunctionEditForYes();
                            dialogRef.close;
                        }
```

it should be dialogRef.close();

```
                        buttons: [ {
                        label: 'Yes',
                        cssClass: 'btn-success',
                        action: function(dialogRef) {
                            doFunctionEditForYes();
                            dialogRef.close();
                        }
```

You're missing the () only - almost had it

updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xh3xhgb3/

Comment: It's an easy enough mistake to make. I've been doing this for years and always miss parenthesis and other little things still :)